# File Upload Issue on VF Page (Customer Community )

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have one picklist on VF page based on changes this picklist I am rendering one VF component which contains some input fields. With the help of I am trying to create a case and Attachment (case related list ). the case created successfully but file not attached. I have checked the debug log which shows attachment body is null.

Please help me out this.

Please help me out this.

<------------ VF page---------------->

```
<!-- jquery datepicker plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>        
<style>
    .navbar .navbar-nav > .flm_Assist > a,
        .navbar .navbar-nav > .flm_Assist > a:focus,
            .navbar .navbar-nav > .flm_Assist > a:hover {
                color: #fff !important;
                background-color: #fbb601 !important;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
.customValildationError{
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #c00 !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #c00;
}
.customValildationError:focus {    
    border-color: none;    
    box-shadow:none;
}
.requiredInput{
    border-left-color: #c00;
    border-left-style: solid;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
.errorMsg{
    color: #c00;
}
.form-control-label{
    margin-top:5px;
}
.loadingBG{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    opacity: 0.5; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    background-color:#23466c;
}
.loadingBGP{
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    z-index: 1001; 
    margin: 15% 50%;        
} 
.lookupInput {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.lookupInput input {
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
.lookupInput a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px !important; 
    height:38px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-image: url(/img/setup/search-icon.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    display: inline-flex !important;
    right:0;
}
.lookupInput a img{
    display:none !important;

}       
</style>  

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $(".customDatePicker").datepicker();            
    });
</script>
<body>
    <apex:form id="IdFrm" html-autocomplete="off">
        <!-- Left Panel -->
        <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
            <c:SideMenuBar />
        </aside>
        <!-- Left Panel -->            
        <!-- Right Panel -->            
        <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">                
            <!-- Header-->
            <c:HeaderBar />
            <!-- Header-->                                
            <!--Main container -->  
            <div class="content mt-3">                                     
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="assist-side-menu">                             
                        <!-- Assist type dropdown menu -->
                        <apex:actionRegion >
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <apex:selectList id="IdPkcList" value="{!selectedAssist}" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary ">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!assistType}"/>
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!actionSupportOCMethod}" reRender="IdAssistFormHeader,IdAssistContent,IdTicketStatus,IdTicketDetails" status="IdStatus" oncomplete="myInit();" />
                                </apex:selectList>
                            </div>                                          
                        </apex:actionRegion>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">                       
                    <div class="assist-content-area">
                        <div class="services-content">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="IdAssistContent">
                                <!-- default msg seciton once page load -->                             
                                <apex:outputPanel id="IdAssistForm" rendered="{!IsAssist}">
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedAssist==null,true,false)}">
                                        <div class="assist-content-area">
                                            <div class="services-content">
                                                <h3>University Services</h3>                                                    
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                    <!-- assist request form section -->                                    
                                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedAssist!=null,true,false)}">  
                                        <script type="text/javascript" >
                                        $(document).ready(function() {     
                                            $(".customDatePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();                                
                                        });       
                                        </script>
                                        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
                                            <div id="IdServiceFrm">                                                        
                                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedAssist=='Academic Services',true,false)}">
                                                    <c:AcademicServices objCase="{!objCase}" attachment="{!objAttach}" />                                                                           
                                                </apex:outputPanel>                                                 
                                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(selectedAssist=='Faculty Services',true,false)}">
                                                    <c:FacultyServices objCase="{!objCase}" attachment="{!objAttach}"/>
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </div>                                                                                        
                                            <br/>                                                
                                        </apex:pageBlock>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>                                    
                                </apex:outputPanel>                                      
                            </apex:outputPanel>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            </div>
            <!--Main container -->
        </div><!-- /#right-panel -->            
        <!-- Right Panel --> 
        <!--  -->
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveCase" action="{!saveCase}"/>
        <apex:actionStatus id="IdStatus">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div class="loadingBG" >
                    &nbsp;
                </div>  
                <div class="loadingBGP" >                        
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:48px;color:#fbb601;"></i>                        
                </div>            
            </apex:facet>           
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:form>                
</body>
<script>           
function checkValidation(){
    var isValid = true;
    var requiredField = $('.requiredInput').find('input, select');
    $(requiredField).each(function(){            
        var isNullBlank = $(this).val();
        if(isNullBlank==''){                
            $(this).addClass('customValildationError');                
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('customValildationError');
        }
    });
    $(requiredField).each(function(){            
        var isNullBlank = $(this).val();
        if(isNullBlank==''){                
            isValid = false;                
        }
    });
    if(isValid){
        console.log('form is valid');
        saveCase();
    }else{
        console.log('form is invalid');
    }
}    
</script>
```

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;background: #23466c;color: #fff;text-transform:capitalize;padding: 0.5em;">
    <h6>Academic Service</h6>
</div>
<!-- Static Field  Section -->
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Assistance Type" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!objCase.HLP_Assist_Type__c}" required="true"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Service Type" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!objCase.HLP_Category__c}" required="true"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Sub Category" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!objCase.HLP_Sub_Category__c}" required="true"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Attendance Exemption From Date" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField id="datetimepicker1" styleClass="form-control customDatePicker" value="{!objCase.Attendance_Exemption_From_Date__c}" />    
</div>
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Attendance Exemption To Date" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>    
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control customDatePicker" value="{!objCase.Attendance_Exemption_To_Date__c}"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label form_label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Subject" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!objCase.Subject}" required="true"/>
</div>    
<!-- attachment section -->
<div class="form-control-label">        
    <apex:outputText value="Attachment" styleClass="form-control-label"/>
</div>
<div class="form-control-label">                                                        
    <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>        
</div>
<!-- submit button -->
<div class="form-control-label" style="margin-bottom: 20px;    padding-top: 25px;">    
    <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary  saveBtn" style="float:right;" onclick="checkValidation(); return false;" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

< !--- Apex Method ----->

```
public pageReference saveCase(){
        System.debug('Save Mehtod start');
        try{
            //-- create new case
            insert objCase;
            System.debug('New Case : '+ objCase);
            IsCreated = true;
            //-------- for attachment upload ----------            
            System.debug('Attach body : '+objAttach.Body);
            if(objCase.Id!=null && objAttach.Body!=null){ 
                objAttach.ParentId = objCase.Id;
                insert objAttach;
            }             
            objCase = new Case();
            objAttach = new Attachment();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            objAttach = new Attachment();
            System.debug('Case Error : '+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you make your problem more specific? It is very hard to understand your problem with such long code snippets.

Comment: Thank you Sanket for quick response. the problem is when i click the submit button i am creating a new case with attachment. the case created successfully but file not attached. attachment body is null every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few changes in your code. The way you were doing is referring to a null value.

In your Controller, define a few variables as follows:-

```
public Blob AttchBody {get;set;}
public String AttchDesc {get;set;}
public String AttchName {get;set;}
Public Attachment attch {get;set;}
```

and In your page change the apex input field as follows:-

```
<apex:inputText value="{!AttchName}" label="name" />
<apex:inputFile value="{!AttchBody}" fileName="{!AttchName}"  />
```

In your controller,

```
    try{
          insert objCase;
          IsCreated = true; 
          if(objCase.Id!=null && AttchBody!=null){ 
          attch = new Attachment(ParentId=objCase.Id,Description=AttchDesc,Name=AttchName,Body=AttchBody);
          insert attach;
         }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Sanket, I have updated my code with this. but still getting the same problem.